# Java Date Time Start and End of day without any TimeZone information

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I have two strings as startDate and endDate. These have values like for example:

```
startDate="2019-09-29T06:00:00.000Z"
endDate="2019-10-06T05:59:59.999Z"
```

Now let us say that these are in Mountain Time as the start of the day for startDate and End of the day for endDate. But as these are Strings, how can I make the program understand that these are can be converted to Mountain local time like:

```
startDate="2019-09-29T00:00:00.000Z"
endDate="2019-10-05T11:59:59.999Z"
```

And the timezone is dynamic. I can get timestamp string from Eastern Time or any other timezone.
**UPDATE**
I realized I should put in more information.
So the Moutain time I have put in is an example. It can be from Eastern Time or any other timezone. The only fact that this method knows is that startDate is the start of the day in some timezone and endDate is the end of the day in that timezone. I understand that 'Z' is the UTC time but finding out which timezone generated that UTC time at the start of the day (startDate) and end of the day(endDate) and converting back to the corresponding local time, is the challenge that I am facing.

Comment: `OffsetDateTime.parse` from the `java.time` package.

Comment: Your first challenge is that *MST*  is ambiguous (like very many three letter time zone abbreviations). Mountain Standard Time or Malaysian Standard Time? Also, is Mountain Standard Time used in September at all?

Comment: If your strings end with `Z`, they are not “without any TimeZone information.”  That Z is a timezone identifier.  Specifically, Zulu time, also known as UTC.

Comment: @OleV.V. - Updated to Mountain time to make sure daylight savings are considered.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, it helps. Can we assume an American time zone? If it can be any time zone in the world, there will be cases near the international date line where the date is ambiguous because the time may be on one or the other side of said line. Within the Americas I don’t think there can be any ambiguities.

Answer (score 4):

The `Z` at the end is time zone information, meaning [offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) 00:00 from [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), aka Zero, aka Zulu, so first you parse the string into a type that stores date, time, and the `Z` timezone.

With Java 8 Time API, that would be [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html), [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html), or [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).
If your inputs always ends with a `Z`, not some other offset, use `Instant`.

You then convert to the desired time zone, which for US Mountain time is called `America/Denver`.

*Examples*

```
String startDate = "2019-09-29T06:00:00.000Z";
String endDate = "2019-10-06T05:59:59.999Z";
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/Denver");

System.out.println(Instant.parse(startDate).atZone(zone));
System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.parse(startDate).atZoneSameInstant(zone));
System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.parse(startDate).withZoneSameInstant(zone));

System.out.println(Instant.parse(endDate).atZone(zone));
System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.parse(endDate).atZoneSameInstant(zone));
System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.parse(endDate).withZoneSameInstant(zone));
```

*Output*

```
2019-09-29T00:00-06:00[America/Denver]
2019-09-29T00:00-06:00[America/Denver]
2019-09-29T00:00-06:00[America/Denver]
2019-10-05T23:59:59.999-06:00[America/Denver]
2019-10-05T23:59:59.999-06:00[America/Denver]
2019-10-05T23:59:59.999-06:00[America/Denver]
```

If you don't want to retain the time zone after conversion, you can remove it by calling [`toLocalDateTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#toLocalDateTime--), e.g.

```
System.out.println(Instant.parse(endDate).atZone(zone).toLocalDateTime());
```

*Output*

```
2019-10-05T23:59:59.999
```

Notice how it doesn't have a `Z` at the end.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear. But the problem is that method does not know from which timezone that corresponding UTC time is created. Mountain time was just an example. It can be EST as well. Only given fact is that startDate is the Start of the Day in some timezone and endDate is end of day in that timezone. Does that make sense or am I complicating it too much?

Comment: @jsmtslch You cannot determine time zone from a pure UTC date-time value, since time zone offsets are ±14 hours, so there is overlap.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn’t keep my fingers off this one, it’s fun. As far as I understood, you don’t know from which time zone the start and end strings come, it could be any time zone. What can we do except try all of them in turn?

```
    String startDate = "2019-09-29T06:00:00.000Z";
    String endDate = "2019-10-06T05:59:59.999Z";

    LocalTime dayStart = LocalTime.MIN;
    LocalTime dayEndEarliset = LocalTime.of(23, 59, 59);

    Instant startInstant = Instant.parse(startDate);
    Instant endInstant = Instant.parse(endDate);
    // Just out of curiosity find candidate time zones
    Set<ZoneId> candidateZones = ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()
            .stream()
            .map(ZoneId::of)
            .filter(zid -> startInstant.atZone(zid).toLocalTime().equals(dayStart)
                    && ! endInstant.atZone(zid).toLocalTime().isBefore(dayEndEarliset))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    System.out.println("Potential time zones: " + candidateZones);
    // Real work: find candidate date(s)
    Set<LocalDate> candidateDates = ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()
            .stream()
            .map(ZoneId::of)
            .filter(zid -> startInstant.atZone(zid).toLocalTime().equals(dayStart)
                    && ! endInstant.atZone(zid).toLocalTime().isBefore(dayEndEarliset))
            .map(zid -> startInstant.atZone(zid).toLocalDate())
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    if (candidateDates.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Cannot identify a date from the instants");
    } else if (candidateDates.size() > 1) {
        System.out.println("Ambiguous date, candidates are " + candidateDates);
    } else {
        System.out.println("The date is " + candidateDates.iterator().next());
    }
```

This prints:

```
Potential time zones: [America/Inuvik, America/Yellowknife, America/Regina, America/Boise, SystemV/MST7MDT, America/El_Salvador, America/Costa_Rica, America/Shiprock, America/Guatemala, America/Denver, America/Belize, America/Swift_Current, America/Managua, Mexico/BajaSur, Canada/Mountain, America/Cambridge_Bay, Navajo, America/Chihuahua, America/Ojinaga, MST7MDT, Pacific/Galapagos, America/Mazatlan, US/Mountain, America/Edmonton, America/Tegucigalpa, Canada/Saskatchewan, Etc/GMT+6, SystemV/CST6]
The date is 2019-09-29
```

And yes, America/Denver is among the candidate time zones as expected. So far I have found the start date. You can find the pair of start date and end date in a similar manner. Possibly you’ll prefer an old-fashioned loop over the stream operation.

However, the date will not always be unambiguous. Let’s try constructing an interval of one day in Pacific/Pago_Pago time zone. It’s at offset -11:00.

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Pacific/Pago_Pago");
    LocalDate testDate = LocalDate.of(2019, Month.OCTOBER, 2);
    String startDate = testDate.atStartOfDay(zone).toInstant().toString();
    String endDate = testDate.atTime(LocalTime.of(23, 59, 59, 999_000_000))
            .atZone(zone)
            .toInstant()
            .toString();
```

Now the output from the program is:

```
Potential time zones: [Antarctica/McMurdo, Pacific/Niue, Pacific/Samoa, Pacific/Tongatapu, Pacific/Enderbury, Etc/GMT+11, NZ, Antarctica/South_Pole, Etc/GMT-13, Pacific/Pago_Pago, Pacific/Midway, Pacific/Fakaofo, US/Samoa, Pacific/Auckland]
Ambiguous date, candidates are [2019-10-03, 2019-10-02]
```

This is because there are also time zones with offset +13:00. We can tell that the offset must be either -11:00 or +13:00, but we cannot tell which of the two. So two dates come out.

**Use half-open intervals for time**

I wasn’t sure whether the end would always be at 23:59:59.999 in the time zone in question, or sometimes perhaps 23:59:59.999999 or something else. Also no matter how many decimals we add, there will still theoretically exist moments that are after that end time but still within the same date. In the code I conservatively accept anything from 23:59:59 and later as end time. The point to avoid the doubt completely is: **Use a half-open interval**. Represent the start of the interval as 00:00:00 as you already do, and the end as 00:00:00 in the date *after* the last date. And treat the start date as inclusive and the end as *exclusive*.